# Having troubles with autolayout xib view - header of a TableView

Tags: ios, autolayout, xib

I'm using a storyboard and created a xib file to represent a header of a tableview, i want it to cover the whole screen. But i cant seem to make it happen.

[image]

then if i simulate with 4 inch:

[image]

As you can see part of my tableview is visible. If i change the the size in the atribute inspector to 4-inch:
[image]

I get the diserd result , but again only if i simulate with the 4-inch simulator. else:

[image]

As you can see im using constraints. What am i missing? thank you